# SQL QUERY : SUM() + Group BY + Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Below is table , I need output which provide me all columns with group by date1 which has sum of salary ( > 6000) for particular date.

```
source table ( INput table ) :
id   name     date1        salary 
1 JOHNSON   1990-12-17    1800 
2 HARDING   1990-12-17    5200 
3 TAFT      1990-12-17    2500 
4 HOOVER    1990-04-02    2700 
5 LINCOLN   1990-04-02    2250 
6 GARFIELD  1990-04-02    5400 
7 POLK      1997-09-22    2500 
8 GRANT     1997-09-22    320
```

Desired output table (below) :   ( last 2 entry 7,8 is not present)

```
id   name     date1        salary   sum(salary)
1 JOHNSON   1990-12-17    1800        9500
2 HARDING   1990-12-17    5200        9500
3 TAFT      1990-12-17    2500        9500
                     ----------
4 HOOVER    1990-04-02    2700        10350
5 LINCOLN   1990-04-02    2250        10350
6 GARFIELD  1990-04-02    5400        10350
                     -----------
```

(Last two values should not come because for that date sum of salary is < 6000)

Comment: Please mark the question with right tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, name, date1, salary ) AS
SELECT 1, 'JOHNSON',  DATE '1990-12-17', 1800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'HARDING',  DATE '1990-12-17', 5200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'TAFT',     DATE '1990-12-17', 2500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'HOOVER',   DATE '1990-04-02', 2700 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'LINCOLN',  DATE '1990-04-02', 2250 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'GARFIELD', DATE '1990-04-02', 5400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 7, 'POLK',     DATE '1997-09-22', 2500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 8, 'GRANT',    DATE '1997-09-22',  320 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         SUM( salary ) OVER ( PARTITION BY date1 ) AS sum_salary
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE   sum_salary >= 6000;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID NAME     DATE1                   SALARY SUM_SALARY
---------- -------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
         4 HOOVER   1990-04-02 00:00:00       2700      10350 
         6 GARFIELD 1990-04-02 00:00:00       5400      10350 
         5 LINCOLN  1990-04-02 00:00:00       2250      10350 
         3 TAFT     1990-12-17 00:00:00       2500       9500 
         2 HARDING  1990-12-17 00:00:00       5200       9500 
         1 JOHNSON  1990-12-17 00:00:00       1800       9500
```

Comment: can you give me query for sql server 2008 and MySQL ?

Comment: @22dj if you want this query for other database platforms, perhaps you ought to attach the relevant tags to your question. And also update your question to include your actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(
select id, name, 
sum(salary) over (partition by date1) sum_sal
from table_name
) where sum_sal >= 6000;
```

Comment: can you give me query for sql server 2008 and MySQL ?

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will work on both sql server 2008 and Mysql :-

```
select * from (
select a.id,a.name,a.date1,a.salary,
(select sum(salary) from table_name b where b.date1=a.date1) Sum_Salary
from
table_name a
) c 
where Sum_Salary >=6000
order by id
```

**Output** :-

```
id  name        date1       salary   Sum_Salary
1   JOHNSON   1990-12-17    1800.00  9500.00
2   HARDING   1990-12-17    5200.00  9500.00
3   TAFT      1990-12-17    2500.00  9500.00
4   HOOVER    1990-04-02    2700.00  10350.00
5   LINCOLN   1990-04-02    2250.00  10350.00
6   GARFIELD  1990-04-02    5400.00  10350.00
```